# Foundation 4.3.2 "Could not find generator foundation:install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I'm running OSx Mavericks, Rails 4.1.1, Ruby 2.1.1. and I'm new to Rails.

Trying to setup Zurb-foundation 4.3.2.  When I run the command `rails g foundation:install` I get the error `Could not find generator foundation:install.`

Googling hasn't helped so far.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your Gemfile has this:

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
```

And not 'zurb-foundation'.

Comment: Foundation-rails is for 5+ only. Zurb foundation is for 4 and below. The generator is malfunctioning for 4.